# How does WordPress Parent-Child Taxonomy actually Works?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

I have created following Taxonomies.

- Parent Taxonomy = WordPress
- Child Taxonomy = WordPress Development, WordPress Plugins

For a specific post, I have set WordPress Development and  WordPress Plugins as custom taxonomy using `wp_set_object_terms()`.

I have expected that it will be automatically set `WordPress` as custom taxonomy for that post because 'WordPress' is parent for WordPress Development, WordPress Plugins taxonomy .

I don't know that my assumptions is correct or wrong because of following points.

- When I use `get_the_term_list()` it returns only WordPress
  Development and WordPress Plugins. So I thought parent taxonomy not
  added automatically.
- But when I got to 'WordPress taxonomy' archive page, that particular
  post is in that archive page.

Now I am confuse how actually Parent-Child Taxonomy works. I mean how that post display in parent archive page but not return when using  `get_the_term_list()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a clarification- you have one *taxonomy*, which contains parent and child *terms*.

When you associate terms to a post, only the terms you select are explicitly associated to that post.

Taxonomy terms are stored in their own table, and parent and child terms are connected to each other in this table.

This is how WordPress can query for posts that have terms that are children of other terms, it gets the children of that term from the term table, and looks for posts that also share those children.